# Book about a girl who had powers to control darkness/night

Tags: story-identification, books

I don't remember the last time I read this book so I only have limited information.

It was about a girl who had powers to control darkness/night. At the start of the book, she ran away from her home with 2 twins (who later in the book get the abilities of water and fire) and another person that I think is a boy. Anyway, while she's running away she dislocates her shoulder jumping of the town/village wall but manages to getaway.

Later in the book/s (I don't remember if it was one massive book or separate ones), she learns to melt into the darkness when she's being hunted down by the evil people.

Just to be clear:
Don't know any names of the characters, don't exactly remember when I read it. Pretty sure the age of the characters was in the 13-17 age range.

If you don't know, it's a fantasy book about a girl who goes on an adventure trying to master her skills and be able to fend for herself. Now that I think about it they received some sort of tattoo that marked what ability they would eventually get when they reach a certain age.

Comment: You might also want to look at [registering your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161) so you don't lose access/ownership of your question and you'll need to know how to [merge accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) in case you accidentally create two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like the [Chasing the Valley trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/series/121035-chasing-the-valley) by Skye Melki-Wegner that came out in 2013.

From the first book's [page](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17739850-chasing-the-valley) on Goodreads:

> Danika is used to struggling for survival. But when the tyrannous king launches an attack to punish her city – echoing the alchemy bombs that killed Danika’s family – she risks her life in a daring escape over the city’s walls.
>
> Danika joins a crew of desperate refugees who seek Magnetic Valley, a legendary safe haven. But when she accidentally destroys a palace biplane, suddenly Danika Glynn becomes the most wanted fugitive in Taladia.
>
> Pursued by the king’s vicious hunters and betrayed by false allies, Danika also grapples with her burgeoning magical abilities. And when she meets the mysterious Lukas, she must balance her feelings against her crew’s safety.

I haven't read the books in a while myself, but the details you mention fit:

- In the books, everyone can use a certain kind of magic once they reach a certain age. This is called a proclivity and manifests itself as a kind of tattoo on the back of the neck that indicates what kind of magic it is.
- The protagonist, Danika, has the Night proclivity, which she discovers near the end of the first book and later uses a few times to melt into the darkness like you said.
- The twins would be Maisy and Clementine, though their proclivities are Fire and Air (Maisy has hers from the start, Clementine finds out hers in book three). The one with the Water proclivity is Radnor, who travels with them during the first book. The boy you have in mind is probably Teddy, who's around for the entire trilogy, or Lukas, Danika's love interest. They're all teenagers, so the age range fits too.
- Danika dislocates her shoulder climbing down the wall of the town where she lives, Rourton, during her escape:*I slip several terrifying metres, but manage to slam one climbing pick back into the mortar. The jolt leaves me breathless, hanging from one arm. Agony tears through my shoulder and I know I’ve dislocated it.*

Comment: This is definitely the correct book. I have the first book so I've added a quote from the part where she dislocates her shoulder. Please feel free to roll back my edit if you don't like it.

Comment: Yes! This is the book. Thank you John Rennie and Sheyffer you guys are absolute legends.

Comment: To be fair, it's my favorite book series of all time :') I was pleasantly surprised to see someone else has heard of it at all.